# Why is the geoserver server status via web administration interface not displayed correctly/accessible?

Tags: server, geoserver, status

I'm using geoserver-2.20.3.war together with Apache Tomcat/9.0.36 on Linux. Everything works as it should but if i try to access the server status via the web administration interface i only get Error messages. I can't really figure out the problem and how to fix it.

`` `HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error ``
`Type Exception Report`

`Message Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.InternalError: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException`

`Beschreibung The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.`

`Exception`

`org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.InternalError: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException`

`...`

`Root Cause`

`java.lang.InternalError: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException`

`...`

`Root Cause`

`java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException`

`...`

`Root Cause`

`java.lang.NullPointerException`
`java.desktop/sun.awt.FontConfiguration.getVersion(FontConfiguration.java:1262)`
`java.desktop/sun.awt.FontConfiguration.readFontConfigFile(FontConfiguration.java:225)`
`java.desktop/sun.awt.FontConfiguration.init(FontConfiguration.java:107)`
`java.desktop/sun.awt.X11FontManager.createFontConfiguration(X11FontManager.java:719)`

`...`

I tried to find a similar issue but unfortunately did not stumble over something really helpful.

Comment: Which version of java are you using? Geoserver only supports 8 and 11

Comment: @ianturton i'm using java version 11.0.13

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution! The problem were missing fonts. After following these very helpful [steps](https://blog.adoptopenjdk.net/2021/01/prerequisites-for-font-support-in-adoptopenjdk/) by Andreas Ahlenstorf and installing the font-package dejavu-fonts on linux everything works fine.